# Different proofs for $\lim nr^n=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

In a lot of places I've seen the use of the ratio test for series to prove that $\lim nr^n=0$, where $|r|<1$. Tried for myself to prove it in a different way. The first that came to my mind was to write $$r=0,\underbrace{999\ldots9}_{K\text{-times}}$$ being this the worse of the cases, but failed miserably in it. Anyway, that's another matter, and I've come to you to ask for other proofs that don't use the ratio test. Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** In my attemps for proving it I got that, if $0<r<1$, then the sequence is decreasing if $$n>\dfrac{r}{1-r}$$ and bounded by $0$, so we know the limit exists.

Comment: Hint: It  is enough to show that $n|r|^n\to 0$. Let $|r|=\frac{1}{1+t}$. By the binomial theorem, if $n\ge 2$, we have $(1+t)^n \ge 1+nt+(n)(n-1)t^2/2\gt (n)(n-1)t^2/2$. (The question has been answered repeatedly on MSE.)

Answer (score 2):

One way to se it:

$$\text{Put}\;\;a_n=nr^n\implies\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{n+1}n|r|\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}|r|<1\;\;\implies\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty nr^n$$

converges (even absolutely) and then it must be $\;a_n=nr^n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\;$