# limit of sequence of functions $f_n(x)=nx(1-x^2)^n$

Tags: limits, uniform-convergence

I have function defined on $x\in[0,1]$ $$f_n(x)=nx(1-x^2)^n$$ 
I need to find its limit function. $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x) \\ $$
Through plotting the function I can determine that $f(x)=0:x\in(0,1]$ I am not able to prove this analytically.

Comment: We still have $\infty\cdot 0$?

Comment: This doesn't converge to any function.

Comment: This question may help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668098/different-proofs-for-lim-nrn-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is clear that $f(0) = f(1) = 0$.

In a very rare cases, a test, such as ratio test or root test etc., for series can deduce whether a sequence converges to $0$ or not.

In this case, root test can be used.

For $ 0 < x < 1$, remember that by [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test) the series  $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty f_n(x)$$
converges if $$C :=\limsup_{n\to \infty} (f_n)^{1/n} < 1 $$
But $C = 1 - x^2 < 1$, which mean the series converge. On the other hand, we know that a series converges implies its nth term tend to zero. Thus $$\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x) = 0$$
for $0 < x < 1$.

Comment: The root test is about convergence of infinite series, i.e. sums, not about convergence of sequences. What is the series in this case?

Comment: @MichaelHardy for a series to converge, its nth term must tend to zero. Saying that the seris $\sum f_n(x)$ converge implies $f_n(x)$ tend to zero

Comment: But how is the series $\sum f_n(x)$ involved in the question? $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy It doesn't directly involved, I bring it here. I just use it so that the problem can be solved easily.

Comment: ok, I think I see what you're saying, but you should make it clear in the answer itself.

Comment: I.e. you could say "By the root test the series $\sum_n f_n(x)$ converges", and then conclude that its terms approach $0. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for the suggestion. It really helps. I'm just bad at grammar and other English stuff, so this is all I can do to make the answer better for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you are correct. Let $x \in (0, 1]$. Then by the continuity of the logarithm we say if $$L \overset{\text{def}}{=} \lim_{n \to \infty} n (1-x^2)^n$$ then $$L = \exp \left( \lim_{n \to \infty }\log (n) + n \log(1-x^2)\right)$$ For our fixed $x$ we can pick $n$ sufficiently large so that we have $\log n \leq -\frac{1}{2}n \log(1-x^2) $, whence for $n$ sufficiently large we have $$ \frac{1}{2}n \log(1-x^2) \geq \log (n) + n \log(1-x^2) $$ and thus we can make the argument of our exponential as small as we like (arbitrarily negative, that is). Thus $L=0$.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is, $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty}nt^n=0$ for all $t\in [0,1)$. Note that, $t=\frac{1}{1+r}$ for some $r>0$. For any $\epsilon>0$ and any positive integer $n>\frac{2}{\epsilon r^2}+1$ we have, $$nt^n=\frac{n}{(1+r)^n}=\frac{n}{1+nr+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}r^2+\cdots+r^n}\leq\frac{n}{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}r^2}=\frac{2}{(n-1)r^2}<\epsilon.$$ So we are done.