# Prove $\lim_{n \to \infty} nx\left(1-x^2 \right)^n = 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

> Show $$\lim_{n \to \infty} nx\left(1-x^2 \right)^n = 0$$ for $x \in [0,1]$.

Method 1:

$nx(1-x^2)^n=nx(1-x)^n(1+x)^n \leq nx(1+x)^n$

Now,

$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} x^k$ which comes out to be $1 + [something \ positive]$ which doesn't help with the $\epsilon-N$ proof.

Method 2:

Using binomial expansion on $(1-x^2)^n$:

$(1-x^2)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} {n \choose k} (-x^2)^k$
$=1 - n x^2 + \frac{n(n-1)}{2}x^4 - \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}x^6$
$+...+n(-x^2)^{n-1}+(-x^2)^n$

I can see some terms are negative and some positive so there might be something in this approach but I am not able to put my finger on it. I am not able to see some pattern that would help me with $\epsilon-N$ proof.

I need some hints pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3422454/513870

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $x$ is fixed, so it is a matter to prove that $na^{n}\rightarrow 0$ for $0<a<1$. Write $\dfrac{1}{a}=1+p$ for some $p>0$, then $\left(\dfrac{1}{a}\right)^{n}=(1+p)^{n}\geq 1+np+n(n-1)p^{2}/2$ and hence $na^{n}\leq n/(1+np+n(n-1)p^{2}/2)\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: How did you get $(1+p)^{n}\geq 1+np+n(n-1)p^{2}/2$? By Bernoulli's inequality I know we can get $(1+p)^{n}\geq 1+np$ but how did you get the extra terms?

Comment: Just expand by binomial formula, no need Bernoulli.

Comment: Ah! Neat trick!

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
1-x^2\le e^{-x^2}\tag1
$$
and
$$
xe^{-x}\le e^{-1}\tag2
$$
we get, from $(2)$,
$$
\frac{nx^2}2e^{-nx^2/2}\le e^{-1}\tag3
$$
Therefore, $(1)$ and $(3)$ yield
$$
\begin{align}
nx\left(1-x^2\right)^n
&\le nxe^{-nx^2}\\
&\le\frac2{ex}e^{-nx^2/2}\tag4
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note:
$$1-x^2=1-\frac1{y^2}=\frac1{\frac{y^2}{y^2-1}}=\frac1C,y>1,C>1$$
Hence:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} nx\left(1-x^2 \right)^n=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{yC^n} \stackrel{LR}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{yC^n\cdot \ln C}= 0.$$